# PHP loop through JSON array from database

Tags: php, json

I have this JSON array stored in my database

```
[{
    "prodid": 1,
    "optionsids": [],
    "extrasids": ["1"]
}, {
    "prodid": 2,
    "optionsids": [],
    "extrasids": ["4"]
}]
```

I am storing it as an array and when I retrieve it in PHP I am going through this and I am 100 % sure it is wrong

```
 $productsarray=json_encode($row['productids']);
 $obj = json_decode($productsarray, TRUE);
```

so I can then loop to get the `prodid` value

```
$products='';
foreach( $obj as $key => $value) {
    $value = get_object_vars($value);
    $products = $products.$value;
}
```

But I am getting an `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` error which means that `$obj` is not an array right? idk how to fix this i have tried various things but with no results.

Comment: If its already stored as json, you dont need to `json_encode` it again when you pull it out of the database. Also when using `true` in `json_decode`, the entire `$obj` will be an associative array, so the subsequent `get_object_vars` can be unpredictable with an associative array fed into it.

Comment: Please provide desired result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is the `string` stored in your database column:

```
[{
    "prodid": 1,
    "optionsids": [],
    "extrasids": ["1"]
}, {
    "prodid": 2,
    "optionsids": [],
    "extrasids": ["4"]
}]
```

If its already stored as json, you dont need to `json_encode` it again when you pull it out of the database.

The following is all you would need to do to get all the `prodid` into a single array to use:

```
$items = json_decode($row['productids'],true);
$products = [];
foreach($items as $item) {
    $products[] = $item['prodid'];
}
var_dump($products);// for debug to see the result

$product_string = implode(',',$products);// to put all prodid in a single string
```